# Unexpected delay on background color change

Tags: javascript, html

Making a small game where a player has to guess what color is being stored.
The intended end result is that when the player guesses correctly a message is shown and the background color changes. However my background color only changes AFTER you dismiss the dialogue box.

here is the code. The part in question is at the very end

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body onload="do_game()">

<script>
var colors = ["blue","red","yellow","green","brown",
          "magenta","purple","aqua","coral",
          "violet","pink","grey","cyan","black","white"];
var target;
var guess_count = 0;
var guess_input;
var game_end; false;

function do_game(){ //Start of function do_game //
        colors.sort();
        target = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        alert(colors[target]);

        do {
        guess_input = prompt(
        "I am thinking of one of these colors \n\n" +
        colors +"\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?")

        guess_count ++;

        }
        while (check_guess());
      } //end of function do_game //

function check_guess(){ //start of function check_guess//
        var color_guess = colors.indexOf(guess_input);
        if (color_guess < 0)
          alert("I don't recognise that color!\n\n"
                + "Please try again");
        else if (color_guess < target)
          alert("Sorry your guess is not correct!\n\n"
                + "Hint: Your guess is aphebetically lower\n\n"
                + "Please try again!");
        else if (color_guess > target)
          alert("Sorry your guess is not correct!\n\n"
                + "Hint: Your guess is aphebetically higher\n\n"
                + "Please try again!");
        else {
          document.body.style.background = colors[target];
          alert("Congratulations!\n\n" + "You guessed " + colors[target]
                + "\n\nThis is correct!\n\n"
                + "It took you " + guess_count + " guesses");
          return false;
        }
          return true;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using an alert box, which stops the execution of Javascript until it is responded to.  You should use a notification `div` (or something like that) to communicate to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that alertboxes stop the flow of JavaScript until they are responded to. You can get around this by setting a one millisecond delay before the alert box is called, through use of a `setTimeout` function:

```
else {
  document.body.style.background = colors[target];
  setTimeout(makeTimeoutFunc(), 1); // 1 millsecond
  return false;
}
```

...

```
function makeTimeoutFunc() {
    return function() {
        alert("Congratulations!\n\n" + "You guessed " + colors[target] + "\n\nThis is correct!\n\n" + "It took you " + guess_count + " guesses");
    }
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v8fg3w92/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Awesome! Learnt something new and solved my problem. Cheers buddy :)